# SQL maximum matching entries

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my SQL question

Table - Activity

```
id activity userID

0 99 1

1 99 2

2 99 3

3 88 1

4 77 2

5 77 3
```

I hope to query this table to generate such a result which pools the choice of activity by

```
different users:

99 1 2 3

88 1

77 2 3
```

My first attempt is using JOIN to self-join the table recursively. But it is a headache. Anyone has other suggestion?

Thanks

Edit:
Another problem. How about if I want to check whether users are friends before grouping?

Table - Friends

```
id userID friendID
0 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 3
3 3 1
4 2 3
5 3 2
```

So they are friends (in both directions). Then I want to do the pooling (GROUP BY) given that they are friends again.

Again, thanks. You guys offer me great guidance.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY activity` and the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: Recursive self-joins might exist in Wonderland

Comment: Adnomar, your comment is a nice analogy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` activity and the `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Like this code:

```
SELECT activity,GROUP_CONCAT(userID,' ') AS Groups
FROM Activity
GROUP BY activity
ORDER BY activity DESC;
```

[SEE THE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9f3e6/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
select activity,GROUP_CONCAT(userID,' ') from Activity
group by activity
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select act,GROUP_CONCAT(userid,' ') from users
group by act
order by act desc
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a270f/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (id int, activity int, userID int);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (0, 99, 1);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1, 99, 2);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (2, 99, 3);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (3, 88, 1);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (4, 77, 2);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (5, 77, 3);

SELECT activity,GROUP_CONCAT(userID,' ')
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY activity
 ORDER BY activity DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT   activity,
         GROUP_CONCAT(userID,' ') AS Groups
FROM     Activity
GROUP BY activity
ORDER BY activity DESC;
```